# Javascript- Incrementing numbers in array in this manner?

Tags: javascript, arrays, increment

How would I go by incrementing numbers in an array like this:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 5]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 6]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 7]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 8]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 9]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

up until it reaches `[9, 9, 9, 9, 9]`. This is a console.log output I need. So I need it to start at `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` This is an array of numbers. I can't necessarily provide code since I don't really know how to go by this. Thank you.

Edit: Why the downvotes? This is a valid question...

Comment: Think about how an automobile odometer works. You increment the last digit. When it reaches 10, you wrap it around to 0, then increment the previous digit. If that also reaches 10, you repeat for that digit and the previous one, and so on.

Comment: You can also just increment a number from 0 to 99999, and fill in the array with the digits of the number.

Comment: you listed the arrays, but is this an array of arrays or objects knowing this would be helpful. can you store it in something for us

Comment: @Barmar Can you provide an example of that

Comment: @Vash Its just an array of numbers, nothing complicated

Comment: @MGames No, I can't. The whole point of this exercise is for you to learn how to program by yourself.

Comment: @Barmar I'm writing this for a key project im working on, not for some "exercise"...

Comment: As for why the downvotes, read [ask]. Asking for other people to write the code for you is not a valid question. We're here to help you, not do your work for you.

Comment: Short of actually writing the code for you, I thought I was extremely helpful with those hints. You say you're not a student, so if you're a competent programmer that should have been enough.

Comment: @Barmar I am a student, but this isn't for an exercise. As for your hints, they were helpful in starting the for loop and getting it started but I asked for an example so I can understand how 555 would become [0, 0, 5, 5, 5].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?
Increment the last digit until it reaches 10 before going to the next one.

```
var arr = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1];

function add() {
 for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   arr[i] = arr[i] + 1;
   if (arr[i] != 10) {
    break;
   }
   arr[i] = 0;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be not very efficient but here is a way to create such incremental array using `Array.from()`:

```js
let arr = Array.from(
  {length: 999},
  (_, i) => String(i).padStart(3, 0).split("").map(Number)
);

console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```